# a client is requesting what are the bandwith requirements for remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, remoteapp

I have about 10 users from this particular customer. He's a cheapo so he's trying to get by with the least he can. What is the minimum a Windows 2008 remoteapp should be per user? Is there any guidelines to go by?

There is no file copying going on, just a remoteapp.

Any ideas?

Comment: The answers in the linked question don't specifically address bandwidth requirements, but the general methodology of determining requirements is there. Essentially, try it out with one or more, setup a lab if necessary, measure, extrapolate, deploy, monitor, correct, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the application.

Any kind of graphic refresh has to be sent over the wire. Typing in a text editor requires a small amount of bandwidth, especially with bitmap caching enabled, as only a small portion of the screen is being updated. Playing a flash game over RDP is extremely bandwidth hungry. Scrolling PDF files with font smoothing in Adobe Reader enabled is an awful experience, especially with high latency links.

You just have to test the application on a limited connection. Use netstumbler or similar to set a bandwith limit for the RDP session and see how the connection behaves. Find some other software to increase your latency, or use a mobile broadband service to see how it behaves over high-latency links.